# Proper way to forward 3rd party API response with Next or Node?

Tags: node.js, next.js

What is the proper way to forward a third party API response (success and fail)?

This is my setup (nextjs API is being used as a proxy for security reasons):

`client -> nextjs api endpoint -> third party API -> nextjs api endpoint -> client`

```
// pages/api/my-endpoint
export default async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('some-url', data);
    res.send(response);
  catch (e) {
    res.send(e)
  }
```

When I do the above I seem to lose data like the body - I need this to work for request success and request failures. Rather than strip out the body I wish to forward the status, body, MIME headers, etc.

Based on [NextJs documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs#api-routes) the `res` object is of type [NextApiResponse](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/v9.0.0/packages/next-server/lib/utils.ts#L168-L178) which extends [http.ServerResponse](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging the response? I would not recommend this to work because a response is more than a body, there are headers, cookies, etc. So you need to make sure that you don't forward the response with just send() or json() but instead inspect and set the proper values.

I suspect this is where you are going wrong.

Comment: I've logged the response and it has a lot of information on it - rather than just strip out data and headers I want to forward it.

Comment: Then you need to pull out and set each part of the response or use something like https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/